# retrieve first occurence of integer in text file

Tags: text-processing

I have the following simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
mtp-files > test_list.txt
echo "Hello World"
ID="$(cat test_list.txt | egrep '^(File) ID: ')"

#read FILE_ID <<<"$ID"

echo $ID
```

It prints out

```
File ID: 6 File ID: 6 File ID: 6
```

But all I need is the first occurrence of an integer value for "File ID" or 6.
What changes are needed in my script?

This is the text file that is loaded

```
libmtp version: 1.1.10

mtp-files: Successfully connected
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Listing File Information on Device with name: Foo Device
File ID: 6
   Filename: 20161208_155851.jpg
   File size 658911 (0x00000000000A0DDF) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 6
   Filename: 20161208_155851.jpg
   File size 658911 (0x00000000000A0DDF) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 6
   Filename: 20161208_155851.jpg
   File size 658911 (0x00000000000A0DDF) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
OK.
```

Comment: can you show the contents of test_list.txt

Comment: done see revised

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "all I need is the first occurrence of an integer value for "File ID" or 6". Does that mean that if the number `6` occurs anywhere before the first `File ID`, then that `6` should be printed? or do you just want the first `File ID` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the first integer from a file, even if more than one occurs on the line:

```
egrep -m1 -o '[0-9]+' /path/to/inputfile | head -n1
```

If only one integer will appear on any given line, the pipe into `head` is superfluous.

If you're searching, as you edited your question to imply, for every unique occurrence of "File ID: ":

```
egrep '^FILE ID: [0-9]+' /path/to/inputfile | sort | uniq
```

To get just the unique numerical IDs, the Rube Goldberg way could be:

```
egrep '^File Id:  [0-9]+' /path/to/inputfile | sort | uniq | egrep -o '[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
mtp-files > test_list.txt
echo "Hello World"
#retrieve only the first ID value
ID=$(awk '/File ID:/{print $NF;exit}' test_list.txt) 
echo $ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `egrep -m1`, I guess you use GNU Grep so it has `-m` option.